# Migrating ZF2 to ZF3: Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment was not found in the plugin manager

Tags: migration, zend-framework3, zend-servicemanager

I'm migrating a ZF2 application to ZF3.

First I was getting the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\Exception\RuntimeException: Could not find a valid ServiceManager for RoutePluginManager in /var/www/work/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/Listener/ServiceListener.php on line 202
Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\Exception\RuntimeException: Could not find a valid ServiceManager for RoutePluginManager in /var/www/work/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/Listener/ServiceListener.php on line 202
```

Adding of `'Zend\Router'` to the `modules` array in the `application.config.php` solved the issue. But now I'm getting another error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: A plugin by the name "Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment" was not found in the plugin manager Zend\Router\RoutePluginManager in /var/www/work/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/AbstractPluginManager.php on line 131
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: A plugin by the name "Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment" was not found in the plugin manager Zend\Router\RoutePluginManager in /var/www/work/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/AbstractPluginManager.php on line 131
```

**What might cause this error and how to fix it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caused by `Zend\Mvc\Router` has been moved to `Zend\Router`, so just replace `Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment` to `Zend\Router\Http\Segment`